# how do a merge of sql server with mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have done this with a foreach and execute dll operation, but when try insert o uptdate a string  throw a exeption, however with a int values works.

The exeption:`Exception stack is:

```
1. Invalid column name 'Carlos'. (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException)
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:217 (null)
2. Invalid column name 'Carlos'. (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException). Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor:93 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'Carlos'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:865)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:2198)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.autogeneratedkey.NoAutoGeneratedKeyStrategy.executeUpdate(NoAutoGeneratedKeyStrategy.java:59)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.executor.UpdateExecutor.doExecuteQuery(UpdateExecutor.java:43)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.executor.UpdateExecutor.doExecuteQuery(UpdateExecutor.java:37)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.executor.AbstractSingleQueryExecutor.execute(AbstractSingleQueryExecutor.java:38)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.ExecuteDdlMessageProcessor.doExecuteQuery(ExecuteDdlMessageProcessor.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.executeQuery(AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.java:42)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.processParts(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:129)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.process(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.Foreach.process(Foreach.java:94)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at o...
********************************************************************************
`
```

'Carlos' is a value from the payload.

This is the DLL

```
BEGIN MERGE [FP].[Profile] AS DESTINO USING (SELECT #[payload.ID]) AS
FUENTE (ID) ON (DESTINO.ID=FUENTE.ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
[UserId]= #[payload.UserId] WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
(ID,UserId,ExternalId,FirstName) VALUES (#[payload.ID],#
[payload.UserId],#[payload.ExternalId],#[payload.FirstName]); END
```

The XML Flow:

```
<flow name="insertprofilesindwFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\LBonaventura\Documents\MuleFilesFromDB" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Read the file with the profiles" moveToDirectory="C:\Users\LBonaventura\Documents\MuleFilesFromDB" pollingFrequency="864000000"/>
     <dw:transform-message metadata:id="57e39ab0-6c79-4118-a57e-fe6561a04e9b" doc:name="Transform Message  to map">
        <dw:input-payload doc:sample="list_csv_1.csv"/>
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0 %output application/java ---payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {


ID: payload01.ID,

ExternalId: payload01.ID as :string,
UserId: payload01.UserId,

FirstName: payload01.FirstName,


LastName: payload01.LastName,



(DateOfBirth: payload01.DateOfBirth as :string) when payload01.DateOfBirth != "",


(DateOfBirth: null) when payload01.DateOfBirth=="",



(Gender:"M") when  payload01.Gender=="1",


(Gender:"F") when  payload01.Gender=="0",


(Gender:null) when payload01.Gender=="",




AllowTracking: payload01.AllowTracking,


Email: payload01.AlertEmail, 

MainProfile: payload01.Main,


Active: payload01.Active as :boolean,
CreatedOn: payload01.DateAdded as :string,
UpdatedOn: payload01.DateUpdated as :string,


LanguageIso: "ESP",


Deleted: false})]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each Profile">
        <db:execute-ddl config-ref="FOX_DW_DATABASE_CONFIGURATION" doc:name="Upsert in the Database">
            <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[BEGIN MERGE [FP].[Profile] AS DESTINO
USING (SELECT #[payload.ID]) AS FUENTE (ID)
ON (DESTINO.ID=FUENTE.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 

        [UserId]= #[payload.UserId],
        [FirstName]=#[payload.FirstName]


WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    INSERT 
        (ID,UserId,ExternalId,[FirstName])
    VALUES
       (#[payload.ID],#[payload.UserId],#[payload.ExternalId],#[payload.FirstName]); END]]></db:dynamic-query>
        </db:execute-ddl>
    </foreach>

</flow>
```

Comment: here the operation:

> BEGIN
MERGE [FP].[Profile] AS DESTINO
 USING (SELECT #[payload.ID]) AS FUENTE (ID)
 ON (DESTINO.ID=FUENTE.ID)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
 
   [UserId]= #[payload.UserId]
   
  
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 
  INSERT 
   (ID,UserId,ExternalId,FirstName)
      VALUES
           (#[payload.ID],#[payload.UserId],#[payload.ExternalId],#[payload.FirstName]);
           
END

Comment: Can you post your full xml flow ? This could help

Comment: Have you tried to write the query without square brackets around column like  MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
UserId=

Comment: @MauroRocco i edited the question, and  put the xml.

Comment: @MauroRocco i tried without square brackets, but the exeption continues.

Comment: Hi, I think in dynamic query you are forced to use quotes becouse there is no param evaluation and therefore no protection from injection.
Have you tried this ?[FirstName]='#[payload.FirstName]'

Comment: yeeeeees, thank you very very much. you saved me.@MauroRocco

Comment: You are welcome, I will write the comment as answer so you can mark it as correct,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with dynamic query there is no parameter conversion, for this reason you need to add quotes to string arguments, so in your case it should look something like that:

```
<db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[BEGIN MERGE [FP].[Profile] AS DESTINO
USING (SELECT #[payload.ID]) AS FUENTE (ID)
ON (DESTINO.ID=FUENTE.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        [UserId]= '#[payload.UserId]',
        [FirstName]=#[payload.FirstName]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
        (ID,UserId,ExternalId,[FirstName])
    VALUES
       (#[payload.ID],'#[payload.UserId]',#[payload.ExternalId],'#[payload.FirstName]'); END]]></db:dynamic-query>
```

Just one note on security: Pay attention when using dynamic query, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection in this way, so make sure you sanitize this parameters before passing it to the DLL.

Comment: how do we handle date type parameters? single quotes should be added  if the parameter is not null and quotes should not be added if its null

Comment: Yes, you need to handle like a string concatenation. Some people prepare the query before in a flowVar so that they can execute complex if in a groovy or expression component and than just put something like #[flowVar.query]. However if you find yourself doing this often you are probably using the ESB for doing what is not meant to do and remember the injection risk.